# Formulating non negative least square problem

Tags: optimization

I was reading the paper “[Fitting a graph to vector data [pdf]](http://www.machinelearning.org/archive/icml2009/papers/506.pdf)” and I found this
optimization problem: $$
\min_{w,s} ||Mw||^2 + \mu||\mathbf{1} - Aw - s|| $$ subject to $w,s\geq 0$,
where $M$ is a $d\cdot n\times m$ matrix, $A$ a $n \times m$ one and $w$ and
$s$ $m$-long vectors. The authors explain that they use MATLAB least square
routine to solve it. Thus I asumed it could be rewritten as $\min ||Cx - d||^2$
by combining $w$ and $s$ into $x$ but I didn't manage to do it.

Am I on the right way or completly missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have made a typo copying the unnumbered equation on page 3 of the paper. It should be:

$$
\min_{w,s} ||Mw||^2 + \mu||\mathbf{1} - Aw - s||^2 $$

This is equivalent to

$$\min_{w,t} ||Mw||^2 + \mu||\mathbf{1} - t||^2 $$

where $s = t - Aw$. This is a standard weighted least square optimization problem. If you like, you can even transfer the positive factor $\mu$ into the second norm to simplify it to an unweighted least square problem with the $2m$-long vector $(w,\sqrt{\mu}t)$ as the unknown.

Comment: Thank you for looking at the paper (although I cannot use the typo as an
excuse since I only made it when asking the question). But I am still a bit
confused by the sum. Does it means that I have to call
[lsqlin](http://www.mathworks.se/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) twice or could I use
a block matrix like that to solve directly for the $2m$ vector:
$$C=\begin{pmatrix}
M & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{\mu}I
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Calling the routine twice won't work, as the result typically wouldn't be fully optimized.

Using the matrix C is almost correct. I think it should be this:

$$ \min || \sqrt{\mu} D - C (w,\sqrt{\mu}) || $$

with C as you gave it and D zero in the upper and left quadrants, and the identity in the bottom right:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & \mathbf{1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Sorry for needing lots of edits to get this one right!

Comment: Note that there's a problem with my answer that I only know realized, though:$$ $$
This was still supposed to be a non-negative least-square problem. My substitution is means that this condition can't be passed on as such to a solver routine.$$ $$Maybe it might be more helpful to seek another answer incorporating the [quadprog function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) that the authors claim to have used for solving the equation?